# Data not displaying in php

Tags: php, mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I've got this PHP script displaying booking details. It works fine and displays date, time, doctor and room.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Book appointment
                </h3>
           </div>

           <div data-role="content">
                <h3>
                    Select date/time:
                </h3>
                <br />
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.Doctor_name, t2.Doctor_room FROM Appointment AS t1 INNER JOIN Doctor AS t2 ON t1.Doctor_id=t2.Doctor_id";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

    //this selects the results as rows
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    

    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_name'] = $row['Doctor_name'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_room'] = $row['Doctor_room'];
    }
}
?>  

        <strong>Dates available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select date--</option>
        <option value="3"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_date'];?></option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

        <strong>Times available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select time--</option>
        <option value="3"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_time'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

            <strong>Doctor Name</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Name--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Doctor_name'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

            <strong>Doctor Room</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Room--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Doctor_room'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

                <label for="textarea1">
                Message GP
                </label>
                <textarea name="" id="textarea1" placeholder="">
                </textarea>

                <br />
                <br />

        <a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="booked.php">
                    Book Appointment
                </a>  

             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I went into phpmyadmin and inserted another appointment so the user can have a choice but this appointment does not display and is only displaying one. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: have checked your `doctor` table..?? make sure `record` added from `phpmyadmin` belongs to existing doctor available in `doctor` table.

Comment: try remove if ($num == 1)

Comment: What do I see after `if($num == 1) { }` ? Why is there an empty block?

Comment: You should try to troubleshoot yourself with printing our variables to see where things go haywire. Use "var_dump($var);" to investigate and see what is generated where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a little interesting mistake here

```
if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_name'] = $row['Doctor_name'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_room'] = $row['Doctor_room'];
    }
```

You set it to display data only if `$num==1` but due to those extra `{}` this will display data even if records are more than one. Because that display is not inside your `if` block and that `if` has no impact on your display whatsoever. But the reason you are not seeing more records is because you are fetching only once and not in a loop

It has to be like

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_name'] = $row['Doctor_name'];
        $_SESSION['Doctor_room'] = $row['Doctor_room'];
}
```

Comment: Just tried the code you suggested and got no errors but it still does not display another date and time.

Comment: What is the number of records returned in your variable `$num`

Comment: Same as before if ($num == 1)

Comment: Then that means the query is not returning more than 1 records and that also needs a fix

Comment: try if($num > 0).....

Comment: @Dev if i put that in, it displays as an unsuccessful login